# Exclude items from a view using filter

Tags: list, filter, view

I want to create a view which rules out several items in a list,

**i.e.,** if there are options A,B,C,D,E in column X, I'd like it to contain all list items except those that contain options D or E (**including items that have blanks in that column**). I could make a filter which lists all of the items I don't want to view but for the view.

**But the problem is** that there are also other things I want to include in the filter so I quickly hit the maximum of 10 conditions in the filter.

What I really want is a 'does not contain' option in the filter but unfortunately, there isn't one in SP. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

I did have an idea of using 'is less than' and then inserting a special character before all the list items that I want to exclude. However, I can't seem to find a suitable character - it needs to be something for which any letter of the alphabet counts as less than. Also, I found that blanks are not included when I try this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `is not equal to` operator in your view. Since you say you want everything but D or E, your filter would be:

`Column X is not equal to D or Column X is not equal to E.`

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing (using AND not OR) but this uses up too many of the filter conditions. I need something that can exclude a bunch of column values (e.g, D, E, F, G, etc.) using one condition.  I'm going to edit my original question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Move (part of the) filtering logic into Calculated Column, use the outcome in the filter as Eric describes